# Expresión regular para ignorar partes de un parámetro en una url

Tags: javascript, regex

Dada la siguiente url

```
dominio.com/moda/mujer/?_q=jean&map=category-1,brand,ft
```

estoy buscando una expesión regular para tener el dominio seguido del primer slash y las palabras siguientes al slash, y solamente

```
?_q=jean&map=ft
```

ignorando todo lo que esté en medio de `map=` y `ft`, es decir así

```
dominio.com/moda/?_q=jean&map=ft
```

Lo he intentado de la siguiente manera:

```
let match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*).exec(window?.location?.href
```

pero solo me trae esto

```
?_q=jean&map=category-1,brand,ft
```

¿De qué manera podría hacerlo?

Comment: Si estás seguro de que el formato de la URL siempre será así, sería mejor hacerlo a través de splits. Primero por `/`, luego el último elemento de este resultado por `&` y el último resultado por `,` y ahí filtras solo el valor "ft". Suena a más trabajo pero la verdad es más legible y evitas meterte con regexs ya que no siempre suelen ser la mejor opción para resolver un problema debido a su complejidad y a que muchas veces puedes resolver el problema con subtareas más sencillas.

Answer (score 2):

Si generamos un patrón que coincida con toda la URL, podemos separar por partes. Cuando se usan paréntesis en una expresión regular, éstos no sólo agrupan, también guardan el texto que coincidió. Y de esta forma, podemos usar paréntesis para cada parte de la expresión regular que luego de coincidir queremos mantener en el resultado. Por supuesto, dejando sin paréntesis a las partes que queremos eliminar.

Luego de coincidir, podemos unir cada uno de los grupos, aunque me parece más sencillo usar [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), que nos ahorra unas líneas.

Entonces, hagamos que coincida parte por parte:

1. El dominio `^[^/?]+\/` desde el inicio del texto, todos los caracteres que no son `/` ni `?`, seguidos del primer `/`
2. El primer subdominio `[^/?]+\/`, todos los caracteres que no son `/` ni `?`, seguidos del segundo `/`. Aunque por un tema de hacerlo compatible con una URL que no tenga un subdominio quizás nos conviene hacerlo opcional `(?:[^/?]+\/)?`
   Sin embargo, como es el mismo patrón que el punto 1, podemos unir a ambos como `^(?:[^/?]+\/){1,2}`
3. Otros subdominios `[^?]*` en donde básicamente hacemos que coincida con todos los caracteres que no sean `?` (esto no lo vamos a incluir en el resultado)
4. Todos los parámetros que estén antes del que nos interesa cortar `\?(?:[^&]+&)*?` en donde hacemos que coincida con el primer `?` seguido de cualquier cantidad de parámetros, cada uno de éstos expresados como todos los caracteres que no son `&` seguidos de un `&`
5. El inicio del parámetro que queremos cortar `map=`
6. Todo el texto hasta la última coma `(?:[^,&]*,)*` con un patrón que coincide con todos los caracteres que no son `&` ni `,` seguidos por una `,`, y todo esto repetido todas las veces que pueda coincidir (esto no lo vamos a incluir en el resultado)
7. Y del resto del texto, no deberíamos eliminar nada. Como estamos haciendo un reemplazo, no hace falta hacerlo coincidir, que quede en el string final.

Al coincidir con la URL, nos quedaríamos únicamente con los puntos 1, 2, 4 y 5 (eliminando así las partes 3 y 6). Si ponemos paréntesis en las partes que nos interesa, queda:

```
/^((?:[^/?]+\/){1,2})[^?]*(\?(?:[^&]+&)*?map=)(?:[^,&]*,)*/
```

con 2 grupos de paréntesis. Por lo tanto, vamos a reemplazar lo que coincida por `$1$2`.

Código:

```js
const texto = "dominio.com/moda/mujer/?_q=jean&map=category-1,brand,ft";

const regex = /^((?:[^/?]+\/){1,2})[^?]*(\?(?:[^&]+&)*?map=)(?:[^,&]*,)*/;
const reempl = "$1$2";

let resultado = texto.replace(regex, reempl);

console.log(resultado);
```